# Mapping Hashmap of Coordinates in Hibernate with Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I've just started using hibernate and I'm trying to map walking distance between two coordinates into a hashmap, There can be many connections from one "FromCoordinate" to another "ToCoordinate". I'm not sure if i've implemented this correctly, What annotations do i need to map this MashMap? Thanks

HashMap> coordWalkingConnections = new HashMap>();

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COORDCONNECTIONS")
public class CoordinateConnection implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1624745319005591573L;

    /** auto increasing id number */
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @id
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    public FromCoordinate fromCoord;

    @Embedded
    public ToCoordinate toCoord;


HashMap<FromCoordinate, ArrayList<ToCoordinate >> coordWalkingConnections = new HashMap<FromCoordinate, ArrayList<ToCoordinate >>();

}

public class FromCoordinate implements ICoordinate
{
    @Column(name = "FROM_LAT")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = "FROM_LNG")
    private double longitude;
}

public class ToCoordinate implements ICoordinate
{

    @Column(name = "TO_LAT")
    private double latitude;

    @Column(name = "TO_LNG")
    private double longitude;

    @Column(name = "DISTANCE")
    private double distance;
}

DATABASE STRUCTURE
id  FROM_LAT    FROM_LNG    TO_LAT      TO_LNG      Dist
1   43.352669   -6.264341   43.350012   -6.260653   0.38
2   43.352669   -6.264341   43.352669   -6.264341   0.00
3   46.352669   -6.264341   43.353373   -6.262013   0.17
4   47.352465   -6.265865   43.351290   -6.261200   0.25
5   45.452578   -6.265768   43.352788   -6.264396   0.01
6   45.452578   -6.265768   45.782788   -6.234523   0.01
    .....
    ...
    .

Example HashMap for HashMap<Coordinate, ArrayList<Coordinate>>


<KEY{43.352669  -6.264341}, Arraylist VALUES{(43.350012,-6.260653,0.383657),  (43.352669, -6.264341, 0.000095), (43.353373, -6.262013,  0.173201)}>
<KEY{47.352465  -6.265865}, Arraylist VALUES{(43.351290,-6.261200,0.258781)}>
<KEY{45.452578  -6.265768}, Arraylist VALUES{(43.352788,-6.264396,0.013726),(45.782788,-6.234523,0.017726)}>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Hibernate can map a column to a list of columns like that. If it was a simpler column-to-column mapping you could use @CollectionOfElements, @JoinTable and @MapKey.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion you have to use the interface type of collection in initialization.

Instead of:

```
HashMap<FromCoordinate, ArrayList<ToCoordinate >> coordWalkingConnections = new HashMap<FromCoordinate, ArrayList<ToCoordinate >>();
```

use:

```
Map<FromCoordinate, List<ToCoordinate >> coordWalkingConnections = new HashMap<FromCoordinate, ArrayList<ToCoordinate >>();
```

If you read the hibernate documentation at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html you will read:

> The actual interface might be java.util.Set, java.util.Collection,
>   java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet,
>   java.util.SortedMap or anything you like ("anything you like" means
>   you will have to write an implementation of
>   org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType.)
>
> Notice how the instance variable was initialized with an instance of
>   HashSet. This is the best way to initialize collection valued
>   properties of newly instantiated (non-persistent) instances. When you
>   make the instance persistent, by calling persist() for example,
>   Hibernate will actually replace the HashSet with an instance of
>   Hibernate's own implementation of Set. Be aware of the following
>   errors:

I do not know if this is the only error. 
Hope this would help you.